# How we can restrict running only limited number of copies of an MS Access Application

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have multiple copies of an access application. i want only limited number of copies can run on the system.

I tried to restrict this by storing information in the registry key (HKLU) but i found in case of terminal server, this key is different for each user and then i tried storing information in another registry key HKLM but this key requires application to be run with administrator privileges (which is not possible in all cases).

Futhermore, i planned to store this information somewhere in a text file that would be hidden, but this scenario will create a problem if application shut down in inppropriate manner (Due to application crash or sudden system shut down or some other case) as i will not be able to update the values in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real clear on your question because from your first sentence, I take that as "I want to prevent two or more copies of Access Application XYZ from running" - and I don't know if you mean on one workstation, or across multiple workstations.

Next you want "only limited number of copies can run on the system". To me, that can imply you may want to run multiple copies of Access Applications, but I assume as long as they are different applications?

For starters, take a look at the following links to see if any of those will satisfy your requirements, then if not (or I misunderstood), please update.

I used the following search terms: how to prevent multiple copies of access from running

http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0041.htm

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/A_2104-Avoiding-running-multiple-instances-of-an-application.html

Comment: i want to prevent two or more copies of an Access Application from running on one workstation and that MS access application is same not the different one.

Comment: How is your application being launched: desktop icon, double-click on file name, other?
Are you trying to protect against 'typical user' or 'crafty tech guy"?
One simple method is to check for presence of the 'locking' file (i.e. MyDB.laccdb') with a startup macro or form.

Comment: Application is simply launched directly by double clicking on it.
I can't check for .laccdb file because DB file copies can be at multiple locations in the system.

Comment: So, the issue is not preventing two copies of the same database (and the same file) from running, it is preventing someone from making a dozen copies, spreading around in different folders and running? Again I must ask the level of user - typical or crafty? Also, are your users allowed to do things like make copies? Who manages these workstations? One solution would be to create a back-end database on their workstation, link to a dummy table and open exclusively. But if crafty, user can just make a copy of the back-end and relink! You have a server?

Comment: yes exactly want to restrict spreading copies of application. Yes we allow the users to make copies of application. This application is standalone system and number of copies that can be run is stored in the local table in the encrypted form. The user level should be crafty one.

Furthermore, we will store and manage workstation on a server database through web services.

Comment: If the application(s) contain the code (i.e. not an MDE), a crafty user can get to the code and modify it to negate anything you may try.  You don't mention if there is a back-end or server db involved, so possibly something could be done with that. If you can lock down the code, you could use a startup form, keep track of opens and closes (in a server / back-end) and manage copies by that.

Comment: Application is MDE file and fully secured.There is no server DB is involved, the MDE file itself contains the database and in non shared mode.

Comment: I recently tried to block the copies by fetching the process details from task manager, but the thing is how would i know which process is executing which copy of application.

Comment: Well ! I got success in doing the task.
Thanx for your support.